# Is my email, pc or something else hacked?

Tags: passwords, malware, account-security, phishing

Recently I registered iCloud account with my gmail account. Now I received fake email from "iCloud" on mail.com email address which I use frequently for registering accounts on various sites. **This email address is also recovery address for the gmail account.**

Here's the fake email:

[image: fake icloud email]

Also, something similar happened when I transferred money from paypal to my bank account. Couple days after transferring money, I received fake PayPal email with link (phishing I guess) telling me my paypal acc is limited and I wont be able to send or receive money. That email came to my mail.com account, which I also use for paypal account.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that your account is hacked. I think what you experience here is cognitive bias instead.

Such phishing mails are pretty common and one even gets these without having iCloud or Paypal accounts. Usually one simply ignores these mails. But if one suddenly gets such a mail after creating or using such accounts, one is prone to assume a causal link between these two events - even if none exists.

This cognitive bias does not need to be solely caused by one's own mind. A self-adapting spam filter might play its role too: If usually such phishing mails are treated as spam and automatically moved away, the spam filter might realize that one suddenly has an actual interest in iCloud and Paypal. It might therefore treat new mails about this topic as relevant too. This way one will suddenly be exposed to phishing mails, which in the past would be automatically moved out of sight.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. Too much intelligence is not good for every case.

Comment: I do receive much of these mails and disregard them. With paypal mail I was a little bit suspicious, but I just ignored it. But iCloud mil is very suspicious, because I never received iCloud fake email before and I never owned an apple device before. Now that I bought one and registered an iCloud acc suddenly I get this email.

Comment: @Shoushei: I have no iCloud account and get many iCloud phishing mails. Thus I don't think that there is a casual link.

Answer (score -1):

I think so, your account is hacked. That domain guadeloupe is actually used in creating fake email accounts for phising activity. But I suggest to use this [website](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) to check whether your account is compromised.

Comment: "That domain guadeloupe" has absolutely nothing to do with whether the OP's Gmail account has been hacked. I don't think you understood the screenshot.

Comment: HIBP is of very little use in this scenario...